# Objective-c PushView for a cell of TableView in an other TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, detailsview, horizontallist

I have a problem by showing detail for a selected cell. But this cell is in a TableView horizontal, and this TableView is in a cell of an other TableViewController. I hope you can understand me.

Here the code of the TableViewController (named HostingTableViewController) :

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellWithTableInside";
        CellWithTableInside *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CellWithTableInside alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        NSArray *tabSection = [dictionarySection  keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
            return [obj1 compare:obj2];
        }];
        NSArray* sortedNumbers = [tabSection sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }

            if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];

        id key,value;

            key = [sortedNumbers objectAtIndex: [indexPath section]];
            value = [dictionarySection objectForKey: key];

[cell setCellData:[dictionaryClip objectForKey:key]];

        return cell;
    }
```

Here the code for the Cell for show the detail controller :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailClip *secondVC = [[DetailClip alloc]initWithClip:[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [pushVC.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];


}
```

pushVC is init here :

```
pushVC = [[HostingTableViewController alloc]init];
```

Let me know if you need more informations, or code.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you confused in adding code on cell tap you can compare the tables & add the action by comparing its type (name of table)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView==NameOfYourFirstTable)//first table view cell tap
{
    //write the code for your action
    DetailClip *secondVC = [[DetailClip alloc]initWithClip:[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [pushVC.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
else
{
    //actions on click of other table view cell 
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it when I will get my computer back, my hdd just stop working :/